# Download files and keep archive

Tags: trash, archive

Is there a way to keep the archive of a downloaded file/folder? Currently, the archive is moved directly to the Trash can as soon as the content is expanded.

Thanks

Update: screenshot following MK's instructions:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have to change the preferences for `Archive Utility`, which is the default unarchiver used by the browser.

- Open Finder and go to `/System/Library/CoreServices/` (from the **Go > Go to Folder...** menu option or pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>)
- Open `Archive Utility.app` from that location
- Go to **Archive Utility > Preferences** (or press <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd>)
- In the **After expanding:** dropdown, choose **leave archive alone** (you would currently have this set to "move archive to Trash")
- Quit `Archive Utility.app`

Comment: Very cool - thanks M K. I followed your instructions and got to Archive Utility > Preferences. I've edited my question to show the prefs window. The preferences were already set to "leave archive alone". That doesn't seem to do the job. This is 10.9 so it may be a bug. It may be that I need to delete the prefs and reset them. I will post again. Meanwhile, +1 for a great answer..